# Entries of tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

If I have a pure tensor $v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_n$ in an $n$-fold tensor product $V^{\otimes n}=V\otimes\dots\otimes V$ what is the canonical name for the vector $v_j$? Do I call it the $j$-th *entry* of the pure tensor $v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_n$ or the $j$-th *section* of $v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_n$? Or something else?

Comment: I would use "component" but I do not think its standard...

Comment: Keep in mind that the vector $v_j$ is usually not well-defined: One can find another simple tensor that represents the same element in the tensor product.

Comment: "Factor", perhaps?